# The expected revenue problem

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

**Question :**

A travel agent company organizes a tour with ticket price $\$50$ and the ticket is non-refundable. The company has a bus with $20$ seats. The company knows that the participant might not attend the tour so the company sells $21$ ticket bus. The probability of participant not attending the tour is $0.02$, independent with the other. If the participant attends the tour and there is no vacant seat, the company will pay $\$100$. What is the expected revenue of the company?

**My thought :**

It is obvious the company will get $21\times\$50=\$1,050$ from the ticket selling and the company will pay if there are 21 participants attending the tour. Let $X$ be the random variable for the number of participant attending the tour. We use binomial distribution here with $p=0.02$ and $q=1-0.02=0.98$. So, the expected revenue of the company is $$\$1,050-\$100\cdot P[X>20]=\$1,050-\$100\cdot 0.02^{0}\cdot 0.98^{21}\approx\$984.57$$Is this correct? If not, what kind approach should I use to answer the problem? Any idea? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same result. It looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response @calculus. I really appreciate it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the random revenue of the company.  Let $Y \sim \mathrm{Binomial}(n = 21, p = 0.02)$ be the number of participants that fail to show.  Then the company's revenue is a discrete (location-scale Bernoulli) random variable with probability mass function as follows:  $$\begin{align*} \Pr[X = 950] &= \Pr[Y = 0], \\ \Pr[X = 1050] &= \Pr[Y \ge 1] = 1 - \Pr[Y = 0].  \end{align*}$$  The expected value of $X$ is therefore $$\mathrm{E}[X] = 950 \Pr[Y = 0] + 1050 (1 - \Pr[Y = 0]).$$  Since $\Pr[Y = 0] = (1-0.02)^{21}$, it is a straightforward calculation to obtain $\mathrm{E}[X]$.

Note that the use of explicit parametric models allows us to generalize the problem; we can compute, for example, the expected revenue of the company if they book $n = 25$ seats and for each attendee that shows up in excess of the $20$ seats on the bus, they refund \$100.  In such a case, the relationship between the number of no-shows $Y$ and the revenue $X$ can be described by $$X = \begin{cases} 1050 - 100(5-Y), & 0 \le Y \le 4, \\ 1050, & 5 \le Y \le 25. \end{cases}$$  This permits us to express $\mathrm{E}[X]$ in the following manner:  $$\mathrm{E}[X] = 1050 \Pr[Y \ge 5] + \sum_{y = 0}^4 (1050 - 100(5-y))\Pr[Y = y],$$ where in this case $Y \sim \mathrm{Binomial}(n = 25, p = 0.02)$ if the same individual probability of a no-show is assumed.

Comment: I don't understand, where did you get 950?

Comment: If **everyone** shows up (that is, we observe $Y = 0$), then the revenue of the company is $1050 - 100 = 950.$

Comment: I can understand the 1st term, $950 \Pr[Y = 0]$. But I don't understand the second term, $1050 (1 - \Pr[Y = 0])$. What is the intuitive explanation for the 2nd term? How if the ticket is only sold for $<21$?

Comment: There are only two outcomes of interest with respect to the number of no-shows:  if there are zero no-shows (everyone shows up), then the company has to refund 100.  If at least one person fails to show up, then there is enough space on the bus for everyone who does show up, and the company gets the full 1050.  **Exactly** one of these two possible events occur; that is to say, $$\Pr[Y = 0] + \Pr[Y \ge 1] = 1.$$  You should also note that we are told that the company has sold 21 tickets already.  That is a fixed value.  It's the number of no-shows that is subject to randomness.

Comment: Aha! I get it now. Thank you so much! :-)